# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message) for provide adapters

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-2

I use my own custom adapter classes, but when I want to provide them, I have a problem and I do not understand why!

```kotlin
@Module
abstract class AppointmentListModule {

    companion object {
        @Provides
        @PerChildFragment
        fun adapter(appExecutors: AppExecutors): SingleDataAdapter<AppointmentDigestData> = SingleDataAdapter(
            appExecutors,
            R.layout.item_appointment_patient,
            SimpleDiffCallback(AppointmentDigestData::id),
            BR.item
        )
    }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
error: @Provides methods can only be present within a @Module or @ProducerModule
        public final ir.logicfan.core.ui.recyclerview.adapter.SingleDataAdapter<com.ennings.data.entity.patient.AppointmentDigestData> adapter(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

SingleDataAdapter constructor:

```kotlin
open class SingleDataAdapter<T>(
    appExecutors: AppExecutors,
    @LayoutRes protected val itemLayout: Int,
    diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>,
    private val bindingItemVariableId: Int,
    private val positionBindingVariableId: Int? = null
) : ListAdapter<T, DataBindingViewHolder<T>>(
    AsyncDifferConfig.Builder<T>(diffCallback)
        .setBackgroundThreadExecutor(appExecutors.diskIO())
        .build()
) {....}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: What version of Dagger are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot check it right now, but as it stated [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900) try to add @JvmStatic to the fun adapter(appExecutors: AppExecutors) function. And if you can, please show the SingleDataAdapter constructor

Comment: question body edited!